# Inserting and updating with character `‡` - SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server

I am having a problem with inserting and updating records in **SQL server**.

The error originates from a file encoding problem, but that is not the subject of this question.

I have the following text fragment in my file `"JUSTIÃ‡A"` that originally would be something like `"JUSTIÇA"`

There is a **constraint** that prevents me from inserting duplicate records, so initially a SELECT   checks if there is already a record with the received data.

```
Select * from table where position like 'JUSTIÃ‡A'

--0 results
```

Then an INSERT is made, which gives error due to violation of the **UNIQUE KEY** repository.

When I check in the bank, there is no record with the text `'JUSTIÃ‡A'`, but there is with `'JUSTIÃA'`.

```
Select * from table where position like 'JUSTIÃA'

--1 results
```

In the database, in the previous inserts, the character `‡` has not been inserted.

I would like to know if there is a way to wipe this character from my string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might require to use N as it is special unicode character as below:

```
Select * from table where position like N'JUSTIÃ‡A'
```